# simplest way to count two different things in one mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am testing a way to count two different things from a single mysql table.

It's checking if game keys have been claimed so I can do a counter of claimed/total in a page.

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `game_giveaways_keys` WHERE `claimed` = 1 AND `game_id` = 3) as `claimed`,
  (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `game_giveaways_keys` WHERE `game_id` = 3) as `total`
FROM game_giveaways_keys 
LIMIT 1
```

If I don't add "LIMIT 1" it shows me the same claimed/total in as many rows as there are keys, am I right just to LIMIT it to 1 row, or is there a better way to get the info I want into only 1 row to begin with?

Comment: You don't need anything from `FROM ...`

Comment: Hah that would be why then, that sorted it. I was following some info on doing subqueries and they all had that at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN claimed = 1 AND game_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS claimed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN game_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM game_giveaways_keys
```

This could also be simplified to:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN claimed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS claimed,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM game_giveaways_keys
WHERE game_id = 3
```

Both of these queries have an advantage over your original approach in that they require only a single scan, whereas using two separate subqueries will require at least two full table scans.

Comment: Oh nice, that's a really cool way of doing it. Less table scans is always great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give anything after `FROM`. Your full query should be just:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `game_giveaways_keys` WHERE `claimed` = 1 AND `game_id` = 3) as `claimed`,
  (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `game_giveaways_keys` WHERE `game_id` = 3) as `total`
```